# not able to call the procedure in shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I have the following shell script register as host executable calling a procedure, that will call a concurrent program in oracle , when I submit the job, it has no concurrent program spawn, I am using the same method in other instance before and it will work, wonder if I missed anything.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Get the current date
    #--------------------------------------------------
    HISTDATE=`date +"%m%d%y%H%M%S"`

    #--------------------------------------------------
    # Input Paramenters
    #--------------------------------------------------
    APPSPW=${1}
    USERID=${2}
    USERNAME=${3}
    REQID=${4}
    INTERFACE_PATH=${5}
    AS_OF_DATE=${6}
    FILENAME=${7}

    echo "+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+"
    echo "| 1. Get FTP Info"
    echo "+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+"
    echo "Request Id     : " $REQID
    echo "Used Id        : " $USERID
    echo "User Name      : " $USERNAME
    echo "Interface Path : " $INTERFACE_PATH
    echo "As of Date     : " $AS_OF_DATE
    echo "File Name      : " $FILENAME

    if [ -d $INTERFACE_PATH ]; then
        echo "- 1.1 Folder "$INTERFACE_PATH" exists"
    else
        echo "- 1.1 Folder "$INTERFACE_PATH" does not exist"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+"
    echo "| 2. Check File Exist or Not"
    echo "+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+"
    cd $INTERFACE_PATH

    V_FILENAME="${FILENAME}${AS_OF_DATE}"

    for files in `ls ${V_FILENAME}*`
    do
    echo "File Name      : " $files
    INPUT_FULL_FILENAME="${INTERFACE_PATH}${files}"
    if [ -s $INPUT_FULL_FILENAME ]; then
            echo "File found, now proceed SQL loader"

    sqlplus $APPSPW <<ENDOFSQL
     connect $APPSPW
         SET SERVEROUTPUT ON                                
     DECLARE
       P_ERRBUFF VARCHAR2(4000);
       P_ERRCODE VARCHAR2(100);
       P_FULL_PATH VARCHAR2(400);
       ln_request_id   NUMBER;
       lv_appl_name   VARCHAR2(10) := 'XHGL';
       lvc_sqlloader1 VARCHAR2(30) := 'XHGL_DCASS_STG';
       lv_req_status1  VARCHAR2(1);
       lv_msg          VARCHAR2(1000);
       ln_user_id              NUMBER;
       ln_resp_id              NUMBER;
       ln_resp_appl_id         NUMBER;
     BEGIN

     BEGIN
     SELECT APPLICATION_ID
     INTO ln_resp_appl_id
     FROM FND_APPLICATION
     WHERE APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME = 'XHGL';
     EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Failed to get ln_resp_appl_id');
     END;

      BEGIN
     SELECT FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID
     INTO ln_user_id
     FROM DUAL;
     END;
     dbms_output.put_line('ln_user_id = ' || ln_user_id);                       
       BEGIN
     SELECT FND_GLOBAL.RESP_ID
     INTO ln_resp_id
     FROM DUAL;
     END;


       P_FULL_PATH := TO_CHAR('${INPUT_FULL_FILENAME}');
        dbms_output.put_line('P_FULL_PATH = ' || P_FULL_PATH);              

    FND_GLOBAL.APPS_INITIALIZE(USER_ID      => ln_user_id,
                                  RESP_ID      => ln_resp_id,
                                  RESP_APPL_ID => ln_resp_appl_id);

    XHGL_DCASS_INBOUND_PKG.SUBMIT_CCMS_STG(   P_ERRBUFF,   P_ERRCODE,   P_FULL_PATH );
     dbms_output.put_line('P_ERRBUFF = ' || P_ERRBUFF);
      dbms_output.put_line('P_ERRCODE = ' || P_ERRCODE);


    END;
    /
    exit
    ENDOFSQL
    fi
    done 
    exit 0
```

Comment: What does the shell script log file say? Did it connect to SQL*Plus? Is the PL/SQL program completely ignored? What exactly is happening?

Comment: SQL> Connected.
SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   P_FULL_PATH =
/oracle/products/sit/fs_ne/inst/SIT_perpdbs001/logs/appl/conc/sit/interface/GL/C
CMS/inbound/TRAC001.lis.c3app2d1.15012809134221
error :Encountered an error while getting the ORACLE user account for your
concurrent request.
Contact your system administrator. errmessage :ORA-0000:
normal, successful completion

Comment: it shows connected to sql, but not executing the procedure, I've tried update statement it can work.

Comment: error :Encountered an error while getting the ORACLE user account for your concurrent request    i am not sure what this erro message is about

Comment: Smells like a buggy version Did you check out MOS?

Comment: the MOS said the custom applciation is not registered in datagroup, but I've already registered it.

Comment: After registering the datagroup have you ran autoconfig and bounced the application?

Comment: it is registered before and application is bounced also, but it is not working.